# India Entry Requirement - Foreign Traveller - Passport Validity

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, india, us-citizens

Wanted to check if someone here had first had experience on this.

Traveling to India with my Son (US passport holder) next month. He has a valid e-visa (already stamped last year) that expires on August 2027. However his passport expire on 15 Oct 2024.

Wondering if India impose a six month passport validity on arrival for foreign travelers.

I have not been able to find a reliable source on any Indian government or embassy website that give a clear answer.

I see similar post here but dont have enough reputation points to comment to find user's experience from last year.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/179329/145059

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

It appears to depend on your intended departure date. From [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.html), entering a departure date *after* the passport expiry date returns:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for the period of intended stay.

You can check your specific travel plan via the link above.

Comment: I get following message when I put my details. No, the documentation you hold is NOT sufficient for the journey you have specified in the summary section. i get the same error if I put my expiry date as 01/01/2025. So it might be referring to the visa requirement. Also how reliable is IATA, would Airlines honor this?

Comment: @sk03 See [Is the IATA travel centre reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183684/is-the-iata-travel-centre-reliable).